# Logical && of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, boolean

I'm trying to take a JavaScript array of strings, and return a boolean value based on all the elements in it. A logical `&&` between non-empty strings should return true. I've found simple way to return a bool between two strings, using `!!("String1" && "String2")`.

However, if I had these two strings in an array like `var myArr = ["String1","String2"]`, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [array `every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) combined with a [`Boolean` cast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean):

```
var myArr = ["String1","String2"]
myArr.every(Boolean) // true
```

In fact you could use an identify function, or `String` as well, though to properly convey your intention better make it explicit:

```
myArr.every(function(str) { return str.length > 0; }) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice solution using `every`:

```
function isEmpty(strings){
    return !strings.every(function(str){
        return !!str;
    });
}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/4zx73csv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
function checkArr(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

checkArr(['a','b']); // true
checkArr(['a','']); // false
```

Or you could do it in a slightly hackish one liner:

```
return !arr.join(',').match(/(^$|^,|,,|,$)/);
```

Comment: The one-liner is a bit too hackish, it'll fail on some strings that contain commata. If you must, better use a less common delimiter. Btw, `test` is suited better than `match` here.